# Dificuldade para popular o GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, ado.net

Tenho uma tela que faço a consulta de clientes e preenche um *grid* com as informações que vem do banco, o meu projeto esta separado por camadas ate onde estou funciona, mas não consigo preencher o *grid* com algumas informações, tenho a seguinte situação dentro do `for each`:

```
 Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

 cliente.Pessoa = new Pessoa();
 cliente.Pessoa.IdPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(linha["IdPessoaCliente"]);
 cliente.Pessoa.Nome = Convert.ToString(linha["Nome"]);
 cliente.DataCadastro = Convert.ToDateTime(linha["DataCadastro"]); 
 cliente.DataAlteracao = Convert.ToDateTime(linha["DataAlteracao"]);
 cliente.LimiteCompra = Convert.ToDecimal(linha["LimiteCompra"]);
 cliente.Ativo = Convert.ToBoolean(linha["Ativo"]);

 cliente.Pessoa.PessoaTipo = new PessoaTipo();
 cliente.Pessoa.PessoaTipo.IdPessoaTipo = Convert.ToInt32(linha["IdPessoaTipo"]);
 cliente.Pessoa.PessoaTipo.Descricao = Convert.ToString(linha["Descricao"]);

 clienteColecao.Add(cliente);
```

Os campos do *grid* que vem direto de cliente como por exemplo `cliente.DataCadastro` carrega normal, mas o que é `cliente.Pessoa.IdPessoa` no *grid* aparece escrito "objeto de transferência", ou se eu personalizar o *grid* não vem nada e quando *debugo* vejo que `cliente.Pessoa.IdPessoa` o `IdPessoa` tem o valor correto mas `Pessoa` está escrito `Objeto` de transferência exatamente o que vai para o *grid*.

Comment: Esse "GridView" que você menciona, no WinForms, você quer se referir ao "DataGridView"?

Comment: Isso mesmo, Metalus.

Answer (score 1):

Você está populando o seu DataGridView ?

O DataGridView tem uma propriedade chamada DataSource. Nele você obtem a fonte dos seus 
dados.

Seria algo como:

```
dgvClientes.DataSource = cliente.Listagem();
```

Verifique:

[DataGridView - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

O Cliente.Pessoa não vai aparecer porque não existe representação dos objetos da classe. Em termos simplísticos os objetos nas células mostram o resultado do ToString().

A pergunta que se pode pôr é o que é que esperava que a classe Pessoa mostrasse na célula?

Comment: Paulo Soares, o esperado era que a classe Pessoa mostrasse na célula o IdPessoa, eu achei que cliente.Pessoa.IdPessoa fosse semelhante a uma sequência matemática "A = B = C = 5", onde todos os valores assumem o valor "5", então no caso o IdPessoa = 5 o resultado carregado em cliente.Pessoa.IdPessoa = 5.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se o exemplo abaixo ajuda em alguma coisa:

```
public void MostrarClientes()
{
        string StrCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Oi\\Testando.accdb";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Cliente";

        OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
protected void CarregarDataGridView(String parametro)
{
  MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=NomeServidor;Database=Teste;Uid=root;Pwd=sua_senha;");
  conn.Open();

  try
  {
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO=@CAMPO", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CAMPO", parametro));

    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Load(reader);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

    table.Dispose();
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
  }
}
```